# How to simulate an 'error' event on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, unit-testing, mongojs, noflo

I'm trying to write a test case for a NoFlo component (written by a colleague) - where the component has a "connect" inPort and an "error" outPort like:

```
var self = this; // a NoFlo Component
var mongodb = null;

self.inPorts.connect.on("data", function(uri) {
    mongodb = mongojs(uri);

    self.outPorts.connected.send(mongodb);

    mongodb.on("error", function(error) {
        self.outPorts.error.send(error);
    });
});
```

So based on this code pattern, how should I simulate an erroneous situation (in the test case) so that it sends an error through the outPort?

I tried sending a bad uri like "lcalhost:99999/abcdef", but it doesn't work.

---

**Update**: the original code sends the `mongodb` instance through a "connected" outPort, I cached it to emit the "error" event successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mongojs` extends `EventEmitter`.

Assuming `mongodb` is global, call `mongodb.emit("error", "This is an error")` to activate the `error` event.

If `mongodb` is undefined, try using the value of `self` to get access to it.

More info:

- http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_emit_event_arg1_arg2
- https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs/blob/master/index.js
- http://cjohansen.no/talks/2011/xp-meetup/#70

Comment: Thanks! Although `mongodb` is not global, I can cache it in my test case. *Have updated the code to reflect this*